# What is this event?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Could someone explain what this C# code is doing?

```
// launch the camera capture when the user touch the screen
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => new CameraCaptureTask().Show();

// this static event is raised when a task completes its job
ChooserListener.ChooserCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    //some code here
};
```

I know that **CameraCaptureTask** is a class and has a public method **Show()**. What kind of event is this? what is `(s, e)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When attaching event handlers, you can do in three different ways:

The old fashioned verbose way:

```
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += Handle_MouseLeftButtonUp;
void Handle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  new CameraCaptureTask().Show(); 
}
```

An [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx):

```
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += delegate(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  new CameraCaptureTask().Show(); 
}
```

Or, using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => new CameraCaptureTask().Show();
```

Imagine the last one as a 'compact form' of the one using the delegate. You could also use braces:

```
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => {
  new CameraCaptureTask().Show(); 
}
```

Comment: or even more old fashion without type inference of Handle_MouseLeftButtonUp;

Answer (score 12):

```
(s, e) => new CameraCaptureTask().Show();
```

This is an anonymous delegate ([lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)). This takes 2 parameters (`s` and `e` (which are unused)), and then create a new CameraCaptureTask and show it.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda notation, `s` stands for `sender`, `e` for `eventargs`, the event's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
(s, e) => { }
```

is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). In this case, it's just a quick way of defining a method (an inline method) without having to create a separate method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the syntax you are seeing is a lambda expression. The code you have in a simplistic view is a short hand for the following

```
this.MouseLeftButtonUp += Handle_MouseLeftButtonUp;

void Handle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  new CameraCaptureTask().Show(); 
}
```

Check the references others have given, Lambda expression provide far more.